# How to change material properties with time

Tags: animation, materials, timeline

I'm trying to create a magic halo behind an object. For this I decided (maybe, improperly - but I'm a newbie) to use hair. So I grew up a long hair, assigned an emissive material and made its colour change with location.

But now I also want that halo to gradually change colours as the time progresses. I cannot find any time-based shaders in the nodes collection, only as a composition node - but that one is to my understanding only applicable to the whole scene animation.

Comment: This can be be done with [*keyframes*](http://blender.org/manual/animation/key_frames.html). Almost all values in blender can be animated; to insert a keyframe, hover over the value you want to animate and press `I`. Then switch to a different frame, change the value, and insert another keyframe. The value will now change from the first value to the second over the course of the frames between the two keyframes.

Comment: But well, why can't I add a new keyframe? I tried adding the properties to a keying set, that went well, but adding a frame for that keying set produces "failed to insert any keyframes" error...

Modifying the colours directly seems to produce a keyframe, but I can't see it on the timeline.

Comment: Can you see the keyframes in the [dopesheet](http://blender.org/manual/editors/dope_sheet/dope_sheet.html)?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I haven't seen this Dope Sheet before :-)

Do you have any idea about the keying set problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to set everything up and then click "I" on the color bar.
Next You have to go to the desired time where the colour change will end on the timeline. After that change the colour of the Halo. Finally click "I" on the colour bar again. This sets the selected colour to the selected time on the timeline.

Final Product:
[image: Final Product]
NOTE: Example above is made in Blender Render since it takes a long time for a cycles animation, but this also works in Cycles as well.

BTW This is probably not the kind of "Halo" you are talking about, but it's a good example.